# Change of OVH Primary IPV4 Address

Tags: ipv4, ovh

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the Primary IPV4 address of an OVH Dedicated Server (Ubuntu 20.04) to a Failover IPV4 attached to the server? I am not wanting to configure/attach the failover IP, but rather make it the actual default/primary IP of the server.

Moreover, if I could just make it so all outbound traffic uses the failover instead of the main IP attached to the server, that would also be very useful.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. You can find more information in the [help].

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the help :)

Comment: The OVH doc about failover IP: https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/public-cloud/configure_a_failover_ip/